# Добавление записи в файл через оператор << и макросы (С++) Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Я новичек в С++ пишу на Qt форму диалога проведения исследования. На каждое событие нужно делать запись в файл протокола. На текущий момент я реализовал функцию которая эта делает, но меня просят сделать по другому, более "красиво". Все действия происходят в диалоговом окне, где создается инстанс модели протокола.

```
ResearchProcessingDialog::ResearchProcessingDialog(const ResearchProject &project, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ResearchProcessingDialog),
    m_project(project),
    m_protocol(project)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

На текущий момент я реализовал функцию, которая получает на вход 2 аргумента, тип события и текст для записи. Работает это так: я пишу `m_protocol.write(ProtocolEvent::Research_Start, "Любой текст");` и в файле получаю `2021-04-19T16:11:33   Запуск проведения исследования  Любой текст`.
События представлены ввиде enum, их около 15-ти.
Но от меня хотят чтобы работало так: `Research_Start << "Запуск начала исследования"` и в файле оказывалось тоже самое.
Сказали, что можно посмотреть как сделана библиотека plog, сделать как там. но мне это не помогло. Я примерно понимаю, что мне нужно определить макросы и как то переопределить оператор <<. Но как именно это сделать не пойму.

Насколько я понимаю, в итоге я должен определить макрос `Research_Start` который подставит в мою функцию write первый аргумент, т.е. тип события, а потом считать значение текста после оператора << и подставить его в качестве второго аргумента. Пока нигде не нашел примеров подобного, и вообще не уверен, что такое можно реализовать.
Есть у кого примеры подобного? Как можно такое сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ может выглядеть где то так

```
#include <iostream>


class Logger {
    public:
        std::string date() {
            return "18:01";
        }
};

Logger& operator<<(Logger& log, const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << log.date() << " " << s << '\n';
    return log;
}

Logger Research_Start;

int main()
{
    Research_Start << "Запуск начала исследования";
}
```

Делаем свой класс логгер, определяем оператор `<<` и пишем все, что нужно. Правда если попробовать вывести несколько строк, то они будут каждая с новой строки, но может так и подойдет.

Если нет, тогда есть другие приемы. Здесь строка накапливается, а потом выводится в деструкторе.

```
#include <iostream>


class Logger {
    public:
        std::string date() {
            return "18:01";
        }
    Logger& operator<<(const std::string& s)
    {
        this->s += s;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Logger() {
        std::cout << date() << " " << s;
    }
    private:
        std::string s;
};

#define Research_Start Logger() << "Запуск начала исследования"
#define Research_End Logger() << "Останов исследований"

int main()
{
    Research_Start << " сегодня";
    Research_End << " завтра";
}
```

Конечно, эффективность такого логгера может быть низкой, но тут уже простор для улучшений, можно себе буфер отдельно завести, возможно даже статический. Также написать перегрузки `operator<<` для различных типов, что бы мочь выводить числа или Ваши внутренние типы.

Comment: Нужно как то сделать чтобы событие передавалось. Например на Research_start  он напишет "Запуск исследования", на Research_end напишет "Окончание исследования". У меня события зашиты в enum их около 15-ти.

Comment: поправил чуточку ответ.

Comment: я сейчас смотрю Ваш пример. Я правильно понимаю, что когда мы пишем `Research_Start << " сегодня";`, то срабатывает макрос `Logger() << "Запуск начала исследования"` он создает инстанс класса Logger? И так каждый раз будет создаваться?

Comment: да, будет каждый раз создаваться. Но он там маленький и  накладные расходы минимальны. просто будет создана строка, в которую сложится строка для вывода и все. Я когда то отвечал одному человеку о накладных расходах в этой конструкции и после профайлинга мы пришли к выводу, что форматирование времени (да, я его упростил до константы) занимает просто львиную долю (больше 50%) работы логера. А ещё там вывод в файл/консоль.

Comment: я просто хочу разобраться как оно работает. А деструктор когда будет вызываться? Я вижу при уничтожении происходит вывод в лог. Получается что он создается и сразу же уничтожается?

Comment: да, в конце строки будет уничтожаться и собственно сделает вывод. Здесь просто создается временный объект без имени, для которого сразу вызываются функции.